# How to concat two double-arrays with streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, concatenation, java-stream

I have two Lists:

Class Matrix: `List<Stroke> stroke = new ArrayList<>();`

Class Stroke: `List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<>();`

Every entry of `points` does map to `{x, y, z}`:

```
points.stream().map(p -> new double[]{p.getX(), p.getY(), 0.0})
```

Every stroke gives a `double[][]`.

Now i want to convert the `stroke` list to `double[][]`.
Since every `stroke` gives a `double[][]` something is need to concatenate every array.

**How to do this with streams?**

```
stroke.stream()....
```

Comment: Is the list of points relevant to your question? Could you give a concrete example of what you want? Input and output?

Comment: @JBNizet: Patrick Parker made a solution and example of what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want something like this:

```
class Stroke {
    List<Point2D> points;
    double[][] toArray() {
        return points.stream()
                // this part you already knew how to do
                .map(p -> new double[]{p.getX(), p.getY(), 0.0})
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
    }   
}
class Matrix {
    List<Stroke> stroke;
    double[][] toArray() {
        return stroke.stream()
                .map(Stroke::toArray)
                // next we will reduce the stream of double[][] to one...
                .reduce(new double[][]{}, (a,b) -> {
                    // ...by concatenating each double[][] with its neighbor
                    return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b))
                            .toArray(double[][]::new);
                });
    }   
}
```

For this task, I have chosen the terminal operation `reduce`. See the relevant [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) for details.

**However**, I would like to point out that this will not be very efficient since you are allocating a fresh array at every reduction stage. You could probably get better results from a mutable container class (such as an ArrayList) using the terminal operation `collect`. Or, even better results with a `Stream<double[]>` instead of using any intermediate containers, as you discovered.

Comment: That is what i was looking for :) thank you! I added a answer below on how i improved the solution (i think it's an improvement).

Comment: Whoever is downvoting this please read the original question: "Every stroke gives a double[][]. Now i want to convert the stroke list to double[][]". I answered the original question using the specified constraints, then I went on to explain the disadvantage of that approach, and finally I suggested a better way. This threefold response is according to SO best practice: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269222

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079181/2230045) of [Patrick Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7098259/patrick-parker) i got an idea of how to solve this.

My solution does look like this:

```
class Stroke {
    List<Point2D> points;
    public Stream<double[]> getArrayStream(){
        return points.stream().map(p -> new double[]{p.getX(), p.getY(), 0.0});
    }
}

class Matrix {
    List<Stroke> stroke;
    private double[][] getArray() {
        return strokeManipulationList.stream()
                .flatMap(StrokeManipulation::getArrayStream)
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
    }
}
```

If there are possible improvements regarding code or performance, please feel free to let me know.

Edit:

Thanks to Patrick Parker again! I replaced the

```
.map(StrokeManipulation::getArrayStream)
.reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat)
```

with just

```
.flatMap(StrokeManipulation::getArrayStream)
```

Comment: I believe you could combine your map and reduce into a simple flatMap

Comment: You are right! The whole reduce step is not necessary. That's a very clean solution.